# How can I use MemberNotNullWhen attribute with nullable enabled in .net6 to fix CS8604 possible null reference warnings?

Tags: c#

I really like the new nullable feature of C# .net6, but sometimes I get possible null reference warnings when I know it isn't possible. I found the attribute [MemberNotNullWhen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.membernotnullwhenattribute?view=net-6.0) from Microsoft, but haven't found any good examples of how this might be used.

I recently discovered a use case for how this attribute can be used and wanted to share to help others who many have been looking for a similar answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** The following example shows a condition where the compiler gives warnings and I know it isn't possible to have a null reference.

```
internal class Response
{
    public IChannelMessage? Message { get; }
    public IsDeferred => Message == null;
}
```

```
Response response = await responseTask;
if (response.IsDeferred)
{
    // NOTE: IsDeferred true means that Message property is null,
    // so we should continue and not run the code below.
    continue;
}

// WARNING: get CS8604 warning on the following line indicating
// that the Message property might be null. This is not possible
// because the IsDeferred check would skip this code if Message
// is null.
await _writeChannel.WriteMessage(
    response.Message);
```

**Solution:** Add MemberNotNullWhen attribute to the Response class to help compiler realize that Message will not be null when IsDeferred is false.

```
internal class Response
{
    public IChannelMessage? Message { get; }

    // FIX: added attribute to let compiler know when Message
    // will or won't be null after checking this property.
    [MemberNotNullWhen(false, nameof(Message))]
    public IsDeferred => Message == null;
}
```

It would be nice if Microsoft had also created the opposite attribute MemberNullWhen so that we did not need to have a double negative coding solution.

Comment: Nullability analysis has two states: "maybe null" and "not null". The state "definitely null" does not occur, so `MemberNullWhen` doesn't fit. `MemberMaybeNullWhen` could exist but is not useful, because it could only meaningfully apply to non-nullable members (since "maybe null" is already the default for nullable ones), and there it would fly in the face of the purpose of NRTs -- a caller would suddenly be confronted with nullability warnings for a member declared not nullable! Hence the negative: you can only specify when a member is *definitely not null*, not when it *definitely is null*.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on this :) I hadn't thought that one through.